Remove trailing letters from a string in BigQuery SQL
I have ID values in a table that look like these:
ABC12345
AAZ54321
ZDA67890
Some of them, however, have trailing letters that I would like to get rid of, like these:
ABC12345A
AAZ54321AZ
Is there a way to use SQL to remove any trailing letters from these strings?

We can use the REGEXP_REPLACE() function with the pattern [A-Za-z]+$:
UPDATE yourTable
SET ID = REGEXP_REPLACE(ID, r'[A-Za-z]+$', '')
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(ID, r'[A-Za-z]$');

Note that if you just want to view the ID with trailing letters stripped, we can use a select query:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(ID, r'[A-Za-z]+$', '') AS ID
FROM yourTable;

